Can't use OpenVPN as client on NetBSD, route add command fails
I am trying to use OpenVPN as a client under NetBSD using this command:
openvpn --client --config /etc/openvpn/config.ovpn

I am getting the following output and errors:
localhost# openvpn --client --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn.ovpn 
2024-04-26 10:29:35 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2024-04-26 10:29:35 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-256-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM:CHACHA20-POLY1305). OpenVPN ignores --cipher for cipher negotiations. 
2024-04-26 10:29:35 OpenVPN 2.6.10 x86_64--netbsd [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD]
2024-04-26 10:29:35 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021, LZO 2.10
Enter Auth Username:********
Enter Auth Password:********
2024-04-26 10:32:48 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]**.191.33.**:1701
2024-04-26 10:32:48 Socket Buffers: R=[32768->32768] S=[32768->32768]
2024-04-26 10:32:48 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]**.191.33.**:1701
2024-04-26 10:32:48 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]**.191.33.**:1701
2024-04-26 10:32:48 TCPv4_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
2024-04-26 10:32:48 TCPv4_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]**.191.33.**:1701
2024-04-26 10:32:48 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
2024-04-26 10:32:48 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]**.191.33.**:1701, sid=0006909e 9b0d208f
2024-04-26 10:32:48 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
2024-04-26 10:32:48 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Ubiquiti Inc., OU=UniFi_OpenVPN_CA, CN=UniFi_OpenVPN_CA
2024-04-26 10:32:48 VERIFY KU OK
2024-04-26 10:32:48 Validating certificate extended key usage
2024-04-26 10:32:48 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
2024-04-26 10:32:48 VERIFY EKU OK
2024-04-26 10:32:48 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=New York, L=New York, O=Ubiquiti Inc., OU=UniFi_OpenVPN_Server, CN=UniFi_OpenVPN_Server
2024-04-26 10:33:53 Control Channel: TLSv1.3, cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, peer certificate: 2048 bits RSA, signature: RSA-SHA256, peer temporary key: 253 bits X25519
2024-04-26 10:33:53 [UniFi_OpenVPN_Server] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]**.191.33.**:1701
2024-04-26 10:33:53 TLS: move_session: dest=TM_ACTIVE src=TM_INITIAL reinit_src=1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 TLS: tls_multi_process: initial untrusted session promoted to trusted
2024-04-26 10:33:53 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,dhcp-option DNS 192.168.7.1,route 192.168.4.0 255.255.255.0,route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0,route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0,route 192.168.3.0 255.255.255.0,route-gateway 192.168.7.1,topology subnet,ping 10,ping-restart 60,ifconfig 192.168.7.2 255.255.255.0,peer-id 0,cipher AES-256-GCM'
2024-04-26 10:33:53 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
2024-04-26 10:33:53 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
2024-04-26 10:33:53 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
2024-04-26 10:33:53 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
2024-04-26 10:33:53 TUN/TAP device /dev/tun0 opened
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 192.168.7.2 192.168.7.1 mtu 1500 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net 192.168.7.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.0
add net 192.168.7.0: gateway 192.168.7.1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net **.191.33.** 192.168.1.254 -netmask 255.255.255.255
route: writing to routing socket: File exists
add net **.191.33.**: gateway 192.168.1.254: File exists
2024-04-26 10:33:53 ERROR: OpenBSD/NetBSD route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 128.0.0.0
add net 0.0.0.0: gateway 192.168.7.1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 128.0.0.0
add net 128.0.0.0: gateway 192.168.7.1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net 192.168.4.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.0
add net 192.168.4.0: gateway 192.168.7.1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net 192.168.2.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.0
add net 192.168.2.0: gateway 192.168.7.1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net 192.168.1.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.0
route: writing to routing socket: File exists
add net 192.168.1.0: gateway 192.168.7.1: File exists
2024-04-26 10:33:53 ERROR: OpenBSD/NetBSD route add command failed: external program exited with error status: 1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net 192.168.3.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.0
add net 192.168.3.0: gateway 192.168.7.1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 GID set to nogroup
2024-04-26 10:33:53 UID set to nobody
2024-04-26 10:33:53 Initialization Sequence Completed
2024-04-26 10:33:53 Data Channel: cipher 'AES-256-GCM', peer-id: 0, compression: 'lzo'
2024-04-26 10:33:53 Timers: ping 10, ping-restart 60

I have a working internet connection when running OpenVPN as a client, but I can't access any of the machines on the network **.191.33.**, I know I should be able to SSH into 192.168.1.114, but I can't reach that machine through OpenVPN, there are firewall rules in the Ubuiquity box allowing traffic from 192.168.7.* to 192.168.1.* I know this is working, its testet from Mac and PC using the OpenVPN Client, I just can't get it to work on NetBSD
This is my routing table before running OpenVPN:
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use    Mtu Interface
default            192.168.1.254      UGS         -        -      -  iwn0
127/8              127.0.0.1          UGRS        -        -  33624  lo0
127.0.0.1          lo0                UHl         -        -  33624  lo0
192.168.1/24       link#2             UC          -        -      -  iwn0
192.168.1.68       link#2             UHl         -        -      -  lo0
192.168.1.254      00:1e:80:a2:2e:ff  UHL         -        -      -  iwn0

This is my routing table when running OpenVPN:
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use    Mtu Interface
0/1                192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
default            192.168.1.254      UGS         -        -      -  iwn0
**.191.33.**/32    192.168.1.254      UGS         -        -      -  iwn0
127/8              127.0.0.1          UGRS        -        -  33624  lo0
127.0.0.1          lo0                UHl         -        -  33624  lo0
128/1              192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.1/24       link#2             UC          -        -      -  iwn0
192.168.1.68       link#2             UHl         -        -      -  lo0
192.168.2/24       192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.3/24       192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.4/24       192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.7/24       192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.7.1        192.168.7.2        UH          -        -      -  tun0
192.168.7.2        tun0               UHl         -        -      -  lo0
192.168.1.254      00:1e:80:a2:2e:ff  UHL         -        -      -  iwn0


This is my routing table after stopping OpenVPN:
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use    Mtu Interface
0/1                192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
default            192.168.1.254      UGS         -        -      -  iwn0
**.191.33.**/32    192.168.1.254      UGS         -        -      -  iwn0
127/8              127.0.0.1          UGRS        -        -  33624  lo0
127.0.0.1          lo0                UHl         -        -  33624  lo0
128/1              192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.1/24       link#2             UC          -        -      -  iwn0
192.168.1.68       link#2             UHl         -        -      -  lo0
192.168.2/24       192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.3/24       192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.4/24       192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.7/24       192.168.7.1        UGS         -        -      -  tun0
192.168.7.2        tun0               UHl         -        -      -  lo0
192.168.1.254      00:1e:80:a2:2e:ff  UHL         -        -      -  iwn0

This is my routing table when i have destroyed tun0:
ifconfig tun0 destroy

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use    Mtu Interface
default            192.168.1.254      UGS         -        -      -  iwn0
**.191.33.**/32    192.168.1.254      UGS         -        -      -  iwn0
127/8              127.0.0.1          UGRS        -        -  33624  lo0
127.0.0.1          lo0                UHl         -        -  33624  lo0
192.168.1/24       link#2             UC          -        -      -  iwn0
192.168.1.68       link#2             UHl         -        -      -  lo0
192.168.1.254      00:1e:80:a2:2e:ff  UHL         -        -      -  iwn0

The route to **.191.33.** is still there when stopping OpenVPN and destroying the tunnel tun0, I don't know if this is expected behaviour.
Update
I have checked several computers now, and none of them have the 192.168.1/24 route, its only on the PC running NetBSD, I have tried to delete it, with no success. I have also read a lot of man pages and various other documentation, but I have not come up with anything usefull yet.
OpenVPN Config
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote **.191.33.** 1701
resolv-retry infinite
nobind

# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

auth-user-pass
remote-cert-tls server
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 3

auth SHA1
key-direction 1

reneg-sec 0

redirect-gateway def1

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<tls-auth>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
...
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>

Intent
I am trying to connect to a VPN at a remote location, from home.
The remote network is protected by a firewall facing the internet, all computers on the network behind the router is accessible, the 192.168.7.* network is standard Ubuiquity and used for VPN clients, I have added a firewall rule to allow traffic from 192.168.7.* to the 192.168.1.* network, this works fine from all computers I have tried it with, Mac, PC, Windows, Linux, MacOS. etc. except a PC running NetBSD.
The network configuration on the PC running NetBSD was performed during installation, and I used the auto-configuration feature, so I have not specified any networks, routes or rules at all.
I am able to access the internet when using OpenVPN client, I just cannot access any of the machines on the remote network. So I guess the part I am missing is the routing from 192.168.7.* to 192.168.1.* so I will be able to access computers attached to that network

I'd say there's a conflict between your local 192.168.1.0/24 LAN and the very same 192.168.1.0/24 remote LAN pushed by openvpn server. If that's the case,  workaround: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16500/how-to-refuse-routes-that-are-pushed-by-openvpn-server

I have just confirmed that the Mac does not have 192.168.1/24 under netstat -nr this could indeed be the problem, on the PC running NetBSD.

You did write in the question: 192.168.1/24       link#2             UC          -        -      -  iwn0

Sorry for the confusion, i have edited my previous comment.

I can't delete that part of my routing table, is there something I can do to remove it?
I have tried route delete 192.168.1/24

Did you check the link I provided?

Yes, I just thought that it was a simpler solution to remove the 192.168.1/24 route, if it was not necessary. I have tried the --pull-filter flag, and I am unsure how to use it, and what routes i should be ignoring.

Time to provide the configurations on both sides. Not the network results, but the actual OpenVPN configuration files on each side. And along this the intent. Normally the intent is deduced from the configuration, but as you appear to have problems, maybe confirm what you actually want to do. For example you appear to both have 1/ problems with 192.168.1.0/24 and 2/ not actually needing to provide it anywhere. Is that really the case?

I know I should be able to SSH into 192.168.1.114, but I can't reach that machine through OpenVPN. You can probably just add an alternative route(s) that has longer prefix manually, e.g. route add -net 192.168.1.114 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.255, or, route add -net 192.168.1.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.128 and route add -net 192.168.1.128 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.128 (just like what OpenVPN is doing for a new "de facto" default route). No familiar with BSD but the reason you can't remove 192.168.1/24 might be because it is implied by the IP prefix.

Note that you still won't be able to, and probably there's no easy way or way at all to, access 192.168.1.68 (or any LAN IP the host is re-assigned with) and 192.168.1.254 of the remote site from this NetBSD host. And you don't exactly need to add a pull filter, AFACIT, since OpenVPN doesn't seem to be bothered by the route adding failure anyway. I don't know if this is expected behaviour. Usually no, btw. In fact you shouldn't even need to destroy the tun interface yourself.

You configured NetBSD telling it that the entire 192.168.1/24 subnet is directly accessible via the iwn0 interface.  If that's not the case then don't configure it that way!  Your local ethernet traffic will not, cannot, go through the tunnel.

@GregA.Woods Very likely it is a "prefix route" added by the OS / network manager when handling DHCP. Even if switching to static IP (with the netmask set to 255.255.255.255 instead) is an option, extra overriding route(s) should make things easier anyway.

No it's not a "prefix" route whatever you mean by that.  It's very clearly shown above with the gateway being "link#2" and with a 'C' flag.  It's effectively irrelevant whether it was configured by DHCP or directly by ifconfig.  The ethernet is configured as 192.168.1/24.  You can see other ethernet members with 'L' flags also in the table with iwn0 as the relevant interface.  As A.B. says, time to provide the configuration files on each side, plus a complete description of the network topology, and the goals of this setup!

I have updated the question with the information requested

I thought you were in control of the server side. I realize maybe not (since no server configuration was provided). I still stand by what I wrote earlier: disable the pushed routes using the link I provided (eg: the answer with pull-filter) to at least verify that's the part failing.

@GregA.Woods By prefix route I mean apparently / obviously the local/physical LAN IP of the host is 192.168.1.68, while the prefix is 192.168.1.0/24 (i.e. the LAN subnet), or in other words the address was assigned with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0. And normally a direct route for the prefix would be added. Whether it is DHCP "matters" because there may be no way to ask your network manager to ignore the subnet mask (i.e., assume 255.255.255.255), whereas in the static case, you can just change your config (and make sure at least a direct route for only gateway is added).

What matters is that the ethernet interface be correctly and completely configured for the LAN it is connected to.  If that is 192.168.1/24 then the current configuration is correct, and it is the OpenVPN config that is broken.  If the LAN carries some other subnet then the current configuration is incorrect.  It does not logically matter how the interface was configured, though if it is via DHCP (as suggested in the update) then it is somewhat more probable that it is correct.  Trying to foil the LAN configuration just to bend to a broken OpenVPN config would be very wrong.

@GregA.Woods Nothing is "broken" / "incorrect" here. When you need to connect to some VPN that is not set up by yourself, you are doomed to have the chance to bump into subnet conflicts, let alone one that expose extra "sites" to you (which is common for a company VPN), and if you need to access a host in one of those sites that conflicts with your LAN subnet, you'll just have to override the route one way or another ("duplicate" with lower metrics, overriding routes of longer prefix length, ...). (Besides, you can't even say at all that "extra" subnets in a home network is wrong.)


I have tried it with, Mac, PC, Windows, Linux, MacOS. etc. except a PC running NetBSD

While I'm not familiar with NetBSD, but based on the route table you  have pasted, and the man page of NetBSD's route command online, it seems that the OS does not support something called route metric, which is basically a number that indicates a route's precedence.
In modern Linux, and probably Windows and macOS as well, it is possible for you to have routes with the same destination (note that destination means the IP range / block that is covered by the route, not the "nexthop" or anything equivalent) in the same route table. (And let's call such route "duplicate routes", even when they are not really "duplicates".) The route with the lowest metric value (highest precedence) would be used for traffics that has a destination that is covered by the routes.
(In fact, in at least Linux, IIRC, you are not forbidden to have "duplicate routes" that have same metric values, including but not limited to the lowest value 0, which can make the value hidden in at least outputs of some related commands. I don't know what exact behavior / policy that would result in though.)
So from what we / I can tell from the outputs / logs you have pasted, NetBSD does not allow duplicate routes and/or route metric. As a result, a route you need for a remote site / host, namely 192.168.1.0/24 (192.168.1/24 is just another form of representation of that), which happens to be the IP subnet used in the local LAN the NetBSD host is in, is not added, which is why you can't access 192.168.1.114 (the one on the remote side).
As a workaround, you can add overriding routes that are not "duplicates". For example, if 192.168.1.114 is the only 192.168.1.0/24 host you need to access:
route add -host 192.168.1.114 192.168.7.1

or, if you want to access as many 192.168.1.0/24 hosts on the remote side as possible:
route add -net 192.168.1.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.128
route add -net 192.168.1.128 192.168.7.1 -netmask 255.255.255.128

(which basically split a 192.168.1.0/24 route into two halves, so that you can have an "effectively duplicate" of higher precedence. If you want to understand the rationale of such override, you would need to dive into L3 networking concepts like VLSM, prefix length and so on, and/or how routing decision is made in general).
If you want these commands to be automated by OpenVPN, you can have equivalent route options in your client conf/ovpn file. (I'm too lazy to give the exact syntax here, but you pretty much just need to stuff in the same sets of "numbers" there. Consult the OpenVPN manual for details.)
With such an approach / workaround, you do NOT need to attempt to get rid of the "original" 192.168.1.0/24 route, since it would be effectively made "dormant".
(Generally speaking, you need to make sure a route specifically for the LAN gateway has been added before you take the approach. In the case of DHCP, often, like in your case apparently, but not necessarily AFAIK, such route is advertised by the DHCP server and/or configured by the DHCP client, given the fact that it's sort of a redundancy to the prefix route in typical network setup.)
Do note that regardless of how you do it, since the destination (192.168.1.0/24) is still a "conflict" between your LAN and the remote site, therefore, if you choose to have route for / obtain access to the remote site, or just one of the hosts like 192.168.1.114, you cannot access the host(s) with the same IP on the local side, not until you remove the added route(s), either by just removing them or destroying the tun interface.
Yet it is more or less impossible to have access to a remote host that is assigned with the IP of your LAN gateway (namely 192.168.1.254 in your case) or the IP of this client host itself (namely 192.168.1.68, which may change to another one if we are talking about DHCP here).

The ERROR: OpenBSD/NetBSD route add command failed lines you see can be somewhat considered harmless. As I mentioned in the command, since/if these errors does not stop OpenVPN from successfully establishing the connection / setup, all you need is to "compensate" what have failed / were missed, namely in your case to add alternate / overriding routes for 192.168.1.0/24 manually. (Although I can't tell for sure whether or not a "non-error-free" connection is the reason that OpenVPN does not revert its operations when the connection is being torn down.)
(The one for **.191.33.** is also harmless because it's just a consequence of a "real" duplicate route for the VPN's "remote address" being found in the route table, due to the fact that your OpenVPN program somehow does not revert stuff it did when it is stopped. I'm pretty sure you won't be seeing it if say, you were connecting for the first time after a reboot. And obviously, nothing you need to "compensate" here. If you want to know why such route is being added, check out the redirect-gateway option in the OpenVPN manual. It's basically for a similar reason I mentioned above for the LAN gateway route.)
You only "need" a pull filter if what you are trying to accomplish is to prevent certain route being pushed by the server from stopping you from accessing hosts on the local side, or, more precisely, via your existing / physical interface. (Certainly that means you don't mind "losing" access to hosts on the remote side that are in the conflicting subnet.) But in your case, NetBSD more or less "did it for you" already, whether you want it or not.

I do think you want to find out why in your case OpenVPN does not revert its "manipulations" (including but not limited to adding the tun interface, i.e. removing it for reversion) when being stop, like whether you are / NetBSD is stopping it in a wrong way or so (e.g. SIGKILL?). I myself have no idea to contribute with that regard though.

NetBSD does have route metrics, but they're set and calculated on a per-interface basis as per ifconfig(8), and perhaps only used by routed(8).

Hmmm.... there are also other metrics directly used in making routing decisions, including RTT and hop count, and these can be pre-set with the route command.  Unfortunately OpenVPN is not yet using these on NetBSD (or other BSDs), if indeed they would work the way OpenVPN wants them to.

@GregA.Woods Well, to be frank, I pretty much know nothing about NetBSD and dynamic / link state / distance vector routing et al, but I'm not seeing any hint anywhere that it supports the kind of "metric" that you can see in route table / that is used in Linux and Windows. (Never really used macOS either.) The key is, AFAIK OpenVPN uses simple command execution for route configuration on most if not all OSes. In Linux, it executes ip route these days, and in NetBSD, as you can see, it execute route, and as I mentioned, the command / program does not accept any metric setting switch / args.

BSD route(8) has has several options to control route "metrics", but they are not called metric, and they work somewhat differently.

@GregA.Woods To be frank, I don't think that's relevant anyway, because the kind of "metric" I have been talking about has one simple purpose: determine which route "duplicate" to use based on this simple numeric value that the duplicates "came with". More importantly, this value has nothing to do with any "context" (or even any "semantics"). Instead, it's purely a user preference. (Even though network manager or so may have default values for you based on "conventions" or the origin or type or whatever of the route, the nature of "this" metric itself is still just a user preference.)

192.168.1.114 is not located on my LAN, its on the LAN on the other side of the OpenVPN tunnel I have checked my Mac, and a PC running Microsoft Windows, using netstat -nr the route 192.168.1/24 was not present on any of the aforementioned computers

The PC running NetBSD is really the only computer I can't connect to OpenVPN with, I guess its because of the OpenVPN Client software or because of the network configuration in NetBSD, since all other computers I have tried with works without any problems

My LAN is very simple, 192.168.1.1 gateway and router, issuing IPv4 addresses using DHCP, and all computers and devices are connected using WiFi. I have no switches, dumb or smart, firewalls, routers etc. connected, besides the gateway.

I have no control of the network on my LAN, its the providers configuration or bridge mode, and i buy my own router, and then there is no support, what-so-ever
Can I fix this network issue by setting the router in bridge mode, and choose, another network like 172.16.0.0 or 10.0.0.0 ? If the issues are caused by some sort of "clash" between the 192.168.1.* network on my LAN and the 192.168.1.* network on the LAN at the other end of the OpenVPN tunnel?

Removing redirect-gateway def1 from the OpenVPN config file makes the problem slightly worse, then no traffic is routed through the OpenVPN tunnel, I have verified this by viewing my public IP address, its my normal address when not having redirect-gateway def1 in the config, and its the public IP of the other network when having redirect-gateway def1 in the config

@user1359448 I've written clearly in my answer that you really just need to add appropriate overriding route on the NetBSD host itself for the 192.168.1.114 (and/or other 192.168.1.x at the remote site, with the stated exceptions) you need to access.

@user1359448 and if you mean whether plugging in another router to "my LAN" (so that you have yet another / an actual "my LAN") would help, yeah, it could. But NOT by putting the router into bridge mode. Instead you must configure it to use some subnet that does not conflict any of those used in your VPN / remote sites and the "now-outer my LAN".

@user1359448 For the record, I've never said / thought that you should remove redirect-gateway def1 from your client conf. Anything I said that is remotely related is nothing but "general discussion".

I understand, just trying things out, and sharing information as i go along, thanks for your time and expertise so far. If I connect to the VPN and do this (from your answer) route add -host 192.168.1.114 192.168.7.1 then im able to reach and SSH into 192.168.1.114, thats seems to be the solution.

This is now a rewrite based on new information from the OP posted as comments to this answer, updates to the question, information pointed out by @TomYan, as well as my own investigations into the source code of OpenVPN.
As a preface let me state it has been many years since I last used OpenVPN.  However fundamentally all the OpenVPN client is doing is authenticating connection then configuring a local tunnel and routes to pass traffic via that tunnel, and then it passes packets to/from the userland endpoint of that tunnel via an encrypted connection from/to the remote OpenVPN server.
I'm also assuming that the "auto-configuration" feature you used during NetBSD installation is the same one I would associate with "use DHCP to configure the network interface", and that you have configured it to use the same, WiFi router and DHCP server as your other local computers are using.

You state in a comment below:

My LAN is very simple, 192.168.1.1 gateway and router, issuing IPv4 addresses using DHCP, and all computers and devices are connected using WiFi.

According to the logs you show that is in conflict with the network routes being pushed by the remote OpenVPN server.
You cannot have two identically prefixed IPv4 subnets in different places and then expect to be able to communicate between them.
So, first off you must reconfigure your local router to use a different subnet.  That can be any of the private RFC 1918 networks, except those being pushed by your remote OpenVPN server.  I would avoid anything with the 192.168 prefix, since that seems to be a favourite of the remote OpenVPN server.
Note you should not have to put your WiFi router in bridge mode.  Just change its LAN address and the subnet it is providing.
Remember to reboot all your local computers after making the subnet change, and test that they continue to work (with and without the VPN) as well.
If you cannot change the subnet of your local WiFi network then (if you want to use that OpenVPN server) you're stuck with having to put another router (with NAT) and WiFi gateway in front of the existing one and set it up so that it NATs to a new unique subnet of your choice.  Such a config would not be ideal though and would be unreliable!

Secondly your local OpenVPN client configuration has the following line:
redirect-gateway def1

The current way the OpenVPN client attempts to implement this, as shown by the log entries below (and confirmed by my reading of the code), is probably incompatible with NetBSD, or any other system with BSD networking code:
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net 0.0.0.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 128.0.0.0
add net 0.0.0.0: gateway 192.168.7.1
2024-04-26 10:33:53 /sbin/route add -net 128.0.0.0 192.168.7.1 -netmask 128.0.0.0
add net 128.0.0.0: gateway 192.168.7.1

These route entries (probably) won't have the desired effect on any BSD system (and if they do it is by accident, not design).  The OpenVPN client has not been properly ported to BSD yet.
So also I would strongly recommend removing the redirect-gateway def1 line from your OpenVPN client config, and replace it with:
pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway

Also as a side note I would say that in my opinion redirecting all traffic through the VPN is rarely ever the best way to set things up.

Finally you say that none of your other computers have a route to 192.168.1/24.  That sounds at face value to be impossible and is quite confusing.  Either those other computers are not on the same LAN as the NetBSD machine, or they are somehow not using the same DHCP server on that LAN, and/or they are not connecting to the same OpenVPN server.  One way or another they should all have a 192.168.1/24 route, at least when their OpenVPN clients are running and connected.
Are you sure all your local computers really are connected to the same LAN via the same WiFi router and DHCP server?  Disable OpenVPN on one of them and reboot it without starting the OpenVPN client, and check again how its network interface is configured.

It probably didn't get removed by OpenVPN because OpenVPN thought it didn't get added in the first place. Somehow in his system, stopping OpenVPN (with whatever means the OP has used) does not revert what OpenVPN has set up. Since the route added for **.191.33.** correctly has the gateway of 192.168.1.254 (hence interface iwn0), it does not get  removed even when the OP manually destroy tun0 afterwards. In other words, it's a "natural" result of establishing the VPN connection "again", given the circumstances. Also, FYR, see redirect-gateway def1.

Ah ha!  So, the default route override is caused by the local client configuration having the statement redirect-gateway def1.  Perhaps that should just be removed, as it may be overriding the LAN route too.  I really wish the OP would respond.  @user1359448 ?

Perhaps that should just be removed well, that depends on whether the OP wants to route "Internet traffics" into the tunnel as well. Also it might at the same time be pushed by the server, in that case it takes a pull filter or so to "remove" it overriding the LAN route too nope, because of how route decisions are made. More "specific" routes (i.e. routes with longer prefix length) always win. (Besides, it is obvious, at least to me, that what the OP exactly need is to override the LAN route, as he is trying to access some 192.168.1.114 host in a remote LAN, not one in his local LAN.)

If the redirect gateway def1 override is (also) pushed by the server then it would have to be rejected with pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway.  The option is seemingly incompatible with BSD as currently implemented.  Probably the OpenVPN client needs to be fixed so that it directly manipulates the actual default route, as otherwise redirect-gateway is impossible.

Looking at the OpenVPN code (route.c:redirect_default_route-to_vpn(), plus how poorly handling of route metrics is ported to BSD) it looks to me like the code is likely unable to support redirect-gateway on any BSD.

192.168.1.114 is not located on my LAN, its on the LAN on the other side of
the OpenVPN tunnel
I have checked my Mac, and a PC running Microsoft Windows, using netstat -nr the route 192.168.1/24 was not present on any of the aforementioned computers

The PC running NetBSD is really the only computer I can't connect to OpenVPN with, I guess its because of the OpenVPN Client software or because of the network configuration in NetBSD, since all other computers I have tried with works without any problems

My LAN is very simple, 192.168.1.1 gateway and router, issuing IPv4 addresses using DHCP, and all computers and devices are connected using WiFi. I have no switches, dumb or smart, firewalls, routers etc. connected, besides the gateway.

I have no control of the network on my LAN, its the providers configuration or bridge mode, and i buy my own router, and then there is no support, what-so-ever

Can I fix this network issue by setting the router in bridge mode, and choose, another network like 172.16.0.0 or 10.0.0.0 ? If the issues are caused by some sort of "clash" between the 192.168.1.* network on my LAN and the 192.168.1.* network on the LAN at the other end of the OpenVPN tunnel?
